# sed command to replace multi-line text with empty

Tags: linux, administrator, sed

I have an XML file which contain portion as given below.

```
<Target name=something>
     < other content here>
</Target>
```

Now how can I remove this content from my file using sed command? I tried the below but didn't work.

```
sed -ir  's/\<Target Name\=.*.\<\/Target\>//g' filename
```

Please advice.

Comment: Depending on the version of regular expressions used `\<` and `\>` may have special meaning: `[<]` and `[>]` will match the literals in all cases. But you will need to do a lot more to match patterns over multiple lines: I commend [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html): not easy reading, but explaining `sed` never can be.

Answer (score 4):

1. you should use XML tools to manipulate XML structures
2. sed is meant to process stuff on a line-by-line basis, you probably want to go for awk to solve this type of substitution.

To solve your problem with awk:

```
awk '/<Target /,/<\/Target>/ { next } 1' your_file
```

**edit:**

just found: sed can do the same thing

```
sed '/<Target /,/<\/Target>/d' your_file
```

Answer (score 2):

[John](https://superuser.com/users/585717/john) has actually [answered](https://superuser.com/a/1081571/598963) the bigger part of your question. However, I noticed that you intend to do in-place editing by providing the `-i` option to `sed`. Note that this option takes an optional argument SUFFIX. If SUFFIX is provided then a backup of the input file is made by adding SUFFIX to its name. The very likely problem in you command line is that the letter 'r' in `-ir` is interpreted as the backup suffix, rather than a separate option `-r`. To achieve the desired effect (when you don't mean to backup files during in-place editing) do not combine other options with `-i` (or make sure that `i` always comes last):

```
# All these do the same thing (in-place editing using extended regular expressions)
sed -r -i ...
sed -i -r ...
sed -ri ...

# This one backs up input files by appending the letter 'r' to their names
# (and DOES NOT use extended regular expressions)
sed -ir ...
```